# Translucent UINavigationBar not working properly on iOS 12 beta (GM seed)

Tags: swift, ios12

I am facing an issue with translucent UINavigationBar on iOS 12.

In a UINavigationController when I am "pushing" a UIViewController which has a translucent UINavigationBar there is bad transition animation on the UINavigationBar and also is not transparent anymore and has a black colour with alpha on top.
The code I used which was working fine on iOS 11.0 was the usual one to set translucency on the UINavigationBar

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
```

Does anyone have the same use case to check if issue happens also?

Answer (score 0):

Instead, why don't you use the utility area to set it to Translucent?

[image: This is the utility area]

Comment: Sorry if this is not helpful.

Comment: You mean from the interface builder or something?

Comment: That's the utility area - You can edit most design things there

Comment: Well in the project we use separate xibs for UIViewController and we want some more global solution to set it and the above code was working before.

Comment: The thing is if you have some app that you used the translucency before and if it behaves correctly or not on iOS 12 beta

Comment: Okay, sorry I couldn't help - Thx for not voting me down

Comment: Well is good to see replies as it can point me something I miss or is done wrong in code.